# What is the need for `fakeroot` command in linux

Tags: sudo, su

Why do we need `fakeroot` command at all? Can't we simply use the `sudo` or `su` commands?

The man page says:

> fakeroot - run a command in an environment faking root privileges for **file manipulation**

About.com says:

> Gives a fake root environment. This package is intended to enable something like: `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot` i.e. to remove the need to become root for a package build. This is done by setting `LD_PRELOAD` to `libfakeroot.so`, which provides wrappers around `getuid`, `chown`, `chmod`, `mknod`, `stat`, ..., thereby creating a fake root environment. If you don't understand any of this, you do not need `fakeroot`!

My question is, what special purpose does it solve that a simple `su` or `sudo` don't? For example, for repacking all installed packages in ubuntu we give following command:

```
$ fakeroot -u dpkg-repack `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1`
```

Can we do the above command with sudo or su instead of fakeroot like this:

```
$ sudo dpkg-repack `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1`
```

**EDIT:**

Running:

```
$ sudo dpkg-repack `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1`
```

gives me this error:

> control directory has bad permissions 700 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)

Any reason why?

Comment: it is a good idea, for security reason, to avoid doing as root everything that could be done as normal user, even if you can run `sudo` or `su` because it is your machine. `fakeroot` has two usages 1) it fools programs into believing you are indeed root user, which some badly written proprietary software may require even if not needed (usually Windows developer gone Linux) and 2) it allow emulating file mode and ownership changes which you wouldn't otherwise be able to do, mainly to create a `tar` file with correct permissions and ownership, useful for example when packaging software.

Comment: I think the note in the excerpt from About.com sums it up: *If you don't understand any of this, you do not need `fakeroot`!* If you can't think of a situation where `fakeroot` is useful, then you literally don't need it. But people who do in fact need it completely understand the use-case.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Imagine that you are a developer/package maintainer, etc. working on a remote server. You want to update the contents of a package and rebuild it, download and customize a kernel from kernel.org and build it, etc. While trying to do those things, you'll find out that some steps require you to have `root` rights (`UID` and `GID` 0) for different reasons (security, overlooked permissions, etc). But it is not possible to get `root` rights, since you are working on a remote machine (and many other users have the same problem as you). This is what exactly `fakeroot` does: it pretends an effective `UID` and `GID` of 0 to the environment which requires them.

In practice you never get real `root` privileges (in opposite to `su` and `sudo` that you mention).

Comment: so, I can't use `fakeroot` to change system settings ?? cuz the command we'll be running will think it's running as root and do whatever we want it do do. won't it ?

Comment: @mrid Note the "In practice you never get real root privileges". So the anwser is no

Answer (score 87):

Since the answers are hard to understand (to myself) and it took some thinking to understand it ([this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9714/what-is-the-need-for-fakeroot-command-in-linux/52866#comment288153_52866) made me understand it), I'm going to give a hopefully better explanation.

#### 1. What happens in fakeroot

Nothing more than what happens with your own user. Absolutely nothing more. If you `fakeroot` (which when called gives you a new shell, like `sudo` would), pretend to do stuff that you needed permission for, and exit, absolutely nothing would happen.

If you think about it, it's a total waste of time. Why would you do stuff that won't actually happen? It's insane. You could have simply not done any of it and there would have been no difference, since there's no trace of it.

Wait a minute...

#### 2. The trace of fakeroot

There *could* be a trace left of `fakeroot`. Let's look at the commands in [MortenSickel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52866/41313) which is pretty nice and deserves an upvote:

```
$ fakeroot
# echo "Wow I have root access" > root.tst
# ls -l root.tst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   23 Oct 25 12:13 root.tst
# ls -l /root
ls: cannot open directory /root: Permission denied
# exit
$ ls -l root.tst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 23 Oct 25 12:13 root.tst
```

At the first glance, it looks like having used `fakeroot` was a total waste of time. In the end, if you hadn't used `fakeroot`, you would have got the same thing.

The subtle thing here is this:

```
$ cat root.tst
Wow I have root access
```

Which means the content of the file still remembers being a root. You might say not using `fakeroot` would have produced the same results. You are right, this example is too simple.

Let's take another example:

```
$ fakeroot
# touch x
# touch y
# chown myuser:myuser x
# ls -l > listing
# exit
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 152 Jan  7 21:39 listing
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser   0 Jan  7 21:39 x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser   0 Jan  7 21:39 y
$ cat listing
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root   0 Jan  7 21:39 listing
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 0 Jan  7 21:39 x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root   0 Jan  7 21:39 y
```

Let's see what happened. I pretended to be `root`, which is totally ineffective, and created `x` and `y`. I pretended `x` to belong to `myuser` and `y` to belong to `root`. They actually both belong to `myuser` (as we can see in the end), but I just *pretended* it to be like that.

Then I created a listing and saved my imagination to a file. Later when I look back at the file, I can see who I imagined the files should be owned by. Again, they are not actually owned by people I imagined, I just simply imagined that.

#### 3. So... Why do you want that again?

You may say that I didn't really need to fake being root to create that listing. I could have simply created the listing, then edited it to reflect my imagination. You are right, you didn't need `fakeroot` for that. In fact, knowing that `fakeroot` doesn't actually do anything, you can't have possibly gained any ability you didn't have before.

**But**, and this is what `fakeroot` is all about, editing the listing could be nontrivial. As it is with a package that can be installed on your system, you have a `tar`ed, `gzip`ed, `xz`ed, `bzip2`ed or any other format that is keeping your files together and remembering their permissions and owners. Can you easily modify the compressed file and edit ownership of a file? I don't know about you, but I can't think of a way.

Could there be a tool built that, once everything is compressed, it modifies the compressed file and programmatically edits the ownerships and permissions? Yes there could. So either you could fake the ownerships before compressing, or change them after. Debian people decided the former is easier.

#### 4. Why not just use `sudo`?

First of all, you don't need root privileges to build software and you don't need root privileges to compress them. So if you don't need it, you'd have to really be a Windows user to even think of getting that permission. But sarcasm aside, you may not even have root password.

Besides, let's say you do have root permissions. And let's say you want to pretend that a file should have read access only to the root. So you `sudo`, actually change the file owner and permissions to `root`, you get out of root shell and try to package everything. You fail because now you cannot read the file anymore since you don't have root access. So you have to `sudo` and compress and build the package as root. Effectively, you have to do everything as root.

This is Bad<sup>TM</sup>.

As a packager, you don't need root permissions and you shouldn't get it. When you install a package, you may need to install some file (`A`) as root and that's where you need root permissions.  All `fakeroot` does is to make this possible. It lets the packager list `A` as owned by root for the archiver, so that when the package is decompressed by the user, the archiver demands root permission and creates `A` as owned by root.

Comment: Excellent writeup, this makes it clear.

Comment: `So either you could fake the ownerships before compressing, or change them after. Debian people decided the former is easier.` This helped me as I kept thinking 'why not modify it after?'.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up the confusion I had after reading @Morten's answer

Answer (score 79):

To see clearly the difference between fakeroot and a real sudo / su, just do:

```
$ fakeroot
# echo "Wow I have root access" > root.tst
# ls -l root.tst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   23 Oct 25 12:13 root.tst
# ls -l /root
ls: cannot open directory /root: Permission denied
# exit
$ ls -l root.tst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 23 Oct 25 12:13 root.tst
```

As long as you are within the fakeroot shell, it looks like if you are root - as long as you do not try to do anything that really needs root privileges. And this is exactly what a packaging tool need to make packages that will make sense on any machine.

In fact, when you use fakeroot for packaging, what you want to achieve is to make the tools you run under fakeroot to see your files as owned by root. Nothing more, nothing less. So in fact, su or sudo will not work for getting the right file ownership.

Comment: Isn’t faker dangerous? If I create a file with the suid bit and rx perm, the file will be created owned by root, executable by anyone, as root! Or maybe setting the suid bit won’t work?

Comment: No good. I tried this out myself. Primary reason for fakeroot is to get ownership root:root into built packages without actually being root. installed packages will have proper perms, though.

Comment: It was all very confusing until I read @ntzrmtthihu777's comment!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the description. Why not patch the tools so that they won't complain if you are not root? As a related question: After all, the files that you create under fakeroot are not *actually* owned by root. Wouldn't this imply that when I install such a `.deb` file, all my `/usr` files are owned by whoever user called `fakeroot`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, no that's the point. The files are not owned by root, but inside a `fakeroot` shell, they _look like_ they are. When the .deb package is created inside this shell, the file owner is read from the file system (which `fakeroot` intercepts and returns `root`) and stored in the package. When installing the package, dpkg then requires root access because the package indicates the file should be owned by root.

Answer (score 36):

AFAIK, fakeroot runs a command in an environment wherein it appears to have root privileges for file manipulation. This is useful for allowing users to create archives (tar, ar, .deb etc.) with files in them with root permissions/ownership. Without fakeroot one would need to have root privileges to create the constituent files of the archives with the correct permissions and ownership, and then pack them up, or one would have to construct the archives directly, without using the archiver.

fakeroot works by replacing the file manipulation library functions (chmod(), stat() etc.) by ones that simulate the effect the real library functions would have had, had the user really been root.

**Synopsis :**

```
 fakeroot [-l|--lib library] [--faked faked-binary] [--] [command]
```

Check more here : [**fakeroot**](http://man.he.net/man1/fakeroot)

Comment: @MaskTheSmokin: So fakeroot gives you super user power only for file manipulation operations,right.

Comment: @gkt.pro : I guess, yes.

Comment: It does not really give super user power, it only fakes it - the program running in it thinks it has root privileges, while it really still uses the user's normal privileges.

Comment: Where is the difference between `the program running in it thinks it has root privileges` and the program having root privileges? If I can do a `rm -rf /` and the program, running it thinks I have root privileges ...

Comment: It still seems weird that it is needed at all. If i can use fakeroot to create a root owned file in an archive and then extract it so that root has it, then why could i not just sudo chown it to root directly?

Comment: @userunknown You might be able to bypass `rm`'s check that you have sufficient permissions, but the kernel itself wouldn't let you do it; the `unlink` system call would fail. It's not up to the application alone to handle permissions, or you'd be able to write your own application that doesn't check permissions and do whatever you want with it

Comment: An example to elucidate the need for `fakeroot` would be fantastic. I can see the uses of fakeroot, but I don't see why people can't work around root permissions to the point that it's easier to fake it.

Comment: Because it is something completely different. it makes your own files look for you like if they are owned by root. - see my example below.

Answer (score 12):

I've used it for package building scripts. I was not sure that the person running the script has root level access, but the script still needed to generate, say, a tar file which contained files that belong to root. The simplest way to do it was run the package building script under fakeroot, which tricked the archiver into believing that the files belong to root, and packed them up as such inside the archive. This way, when the package was unpacked to the destination machine (on a different machine altogether), the files didn't belong to weird or non-existing users.

Thinking about it, the only place I've seen this was for building some kind of archive: rootfs of embedded systems, tar.gz archives, rpm packages, .deb packages, etc.

Comment: `fakeroot` is a workaround tool for bugged packaging software: there is no reason you need to be root to create such packages, but since they don't allow you to specify file permissions in any other way than setting them directly into the filesystem beforehands you have no choice

Answer (score 3):

One common usage is to find out what files a failing binary really wanted to access. That is, finding out and fix or working around bugs caused by hard coded paths and improper exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fakeroot without actually having root privileges. If you had `su` and/or `sudo` you would be able to destroy your system with a simple `rm -rf /`, but with fakeroot at most you would remove your home directory.

Comment: That doesn't explain the need for `fakeroot`. You can remove your home directory as yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer:

su and sudo run commands as root.  fakeroot does not, outside of it's partial sandbox arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good use:

```
$ echo "Hello, world." > root.tst
$ tar cf without.tar root.tst
$ fakeroot tar cf with.tar root.tst
$ tar tvf without.tar
-rw-rw-r-- ubuntu/ubuntu    14 2023-09-19 15:27 root.tst
$ tar tvf with.tar
-rw-rw-r-- root/root        14 2023-09-19 15:27 root.tst
```

The tar file you created without using fakeroot includes your userid in the meta data for the file. This may not be useful on another system because that system may not even have the same user. However, creating the tar file with fakeroot sets the owner to uid 0.

This is a contrived example in that you could accomplish the same thing by adding the "--owner=root" and "--group=root" arguments to the tar command, however there are other applications, such a "dpkg-deb" that call tar without giving an option for passing arguments to it.